# How Can I Subscribe from an Angular Directive to Be Notified of Resize Events?

Tags: dom, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have an element that is sized via Bootstrap and annotated with my custom directive myDirective1:

```
<div class="span4" myDirective1>Hello, world</div>
```

Inside my directive's linking function, I would like to register to know when the element's width changes through, say, a user-initiated browser window resize.

```
element.bind("resize", function() {
    console.log("Resized");

    // Do other stuff
});
```

I'm using Bootstrap's "container-fluid" and "row-fluid" classes, so visually, the element is resizing dynamically just as expected.  However, the binding that I set up for the DOM's "resize" event never seems to fire.  I've verified that "element" is, indeed, the expected element in question.

I am doing this without full jQuery, so it's just using Angular's JQLite.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Not an expert on this topic. It could be that jqLite does not support `resize` event. Just a wild guess. If I were you, I would try with including jQuery and see if there'a difference.

Comment: I think you can only bind `$window` to the resize event, though as the other comment says, you have to use the full jQuery `resize()` method.  Also, rememeber the `$window` has the pure js `onresize()` event attached as well - no jQuery involved.

Answer (score 4):

It is only possible (without a jQuery plugin) to bind `$window` to the `resize()` method, but that does not mean it isn't possible to show the dimensions of an element on window resize().  Here is a directive that binds `$window` to `resize()`, then updates the view to show the new width of a dom element:

```
app.directive('sizer', function($window){
  return {
  controller: function($scope){
    $scope.inputSize = '?'
  },
  template: '<input type="text" style="width:80%">' +
            '<br/>' +
            'Input Size = {{inputSize}}',

  link: function(scope, element) {
    var w = angular.element($window);
    var size = element.find('input')[0].clientWidth;

    scope.inputSize = size;

    w.bind('resize', function(){
      scope.inputSize = element.find('input')[0].clientWidth;
      scope.$apply();

    })
  }
}
```

And [here's the plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/zEsABy2HloVrVNAK5WOX?p=preview).  (In the live view of plunker, resize the pane with the rendered view to see the window size update.)

Also, I was incorrect in the comment above - `resize()` is baked into angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

If you reference the full jquery then you have some interesting options.

I have forked rGils plunker to show the difference. http://plnkr.co/edit/r6i3Y7tXeWNCp1r3LvYq?p=preview

Basically you can use this syntax to get what you want:

```
var resizeHandler = function(){
    //code goes here.
    //added as a var instead of inline so it can be turned off later.
};
$(window).on('resize.sizer', resizeHandler);
```

Where 'resize' is the event and 'sizer' is your directive.

Also, depending on where you are doing this and your app, you may want to remove this event handler... say if your directive is ng-if'd out, in that case you should add a:

```
scope.$on('$destroy', $(window).off('resize.resizer', resizeHandler);
```